# INSERT/VALUES not submitting

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to insert firstname, lastname, etc. however, I think something is wrong my values. Any help on how to values should be worded?

```
            $query="INSERT INTO `users` (`firstname`, `lastname`,`email`, `password`, `gender`, `country`, `state`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')";
            mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $_SESSION['id']=mysqli_insert_id($link); 
            header("Location: dashboard.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the whole thing if needed...

```
if ($_POST['submit']=="Sign Up") {  
    if (!$_POST['firstname']) $error.="<br />Please enter your first name";
    if (!$_POST['lastname']) $error.="<br />Please enter your last name";
    if (!$_POST['email']) $error.="<br />Please enter your email";
        else if (!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) $error.="<br />Please enter a valid email address";           
    if (!$_POST['password']) $error.="<br />Please enter your password";
        else {          
            if (strlen($_POST['password'])<8) $error.="<br />Please enter a password with at least 8 characters";
            if (!preg_match('`[A-Z]`', $_POST['password'])) $error.="<br />Please enter at least 1 capital letter";         
        }
    if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['confirmpassword']) 
        $error.="<br />Your passwords do not match.";
    if (!$_POST['gender']) $error.="<br />Please enter your gender";
    if (!$_POST['country']) $error.="<br />Please enter your country";
    if (!$_POST['state']) $error.="<br />Please enter your state";          

     if ($error) $error = "There were error(s) in your signup details:".$error;
     else {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
        $results = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        if ($results) $error = "That email address is already registered";
        else {
            $query="INSERT INTO `users` (`firstname`, `lastname`,`email`, `password`, `gender`, `country`, `state`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')";
            mysqli_query($link, $query);
            $_SESSION['id']=mysqli_insert_id($link); 
            header("Location: dashboard.php");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query reads like this; code reformatted into multiple lines to show the issue better:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`firstname`, `lastname`,`email`, `password`, `gender`, `country`, `state`)"
       . " VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."')"
       ;
```

So you have seven (7) values for insert, but your actual `VALUES` only has two (2) items. That’s your problem right there. A quick way to see what I mean is to just add null values like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`firstname`, `lastname`,`email`, `password`, `gender`, `country`, `state`)"
       . " VALUES('','','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."','','','')"
       ;
```

But I believe you want to insert all of the `$POST` data like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`firstname`, `lastname`,`email`, `password`, `gender`, `country`, `state`)"
       . " VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['firstname'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['lastname'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['gender'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['country'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['state'])."')"
       ;
```

But the larger issue is you are directly inserting `$POST` data into your MySQL database without an true filtering. So you should consider doing some better validation. But as far as your immediate database issue goes, this should solve the issue right away.

Comment: That only inserts email and password, not first name, last name, etc.

Comment: with the last code, it gives me an error of Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\login.php on line 32

Comment: thank you very much. Will validate the input for sure. It's crazy that even with the dropdown option of gender, even if nothing is selected, because the original value is "select", the form will still be submitted anyway. Hopefully I can figure that out, if not I'll just post another question some other time. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You specify 7 columns to be inserted with the supposed "values", but you only put 3 parameters in the values. And also, when you insert a value to a table here, you should put them in the right order that should be

```
"INSERT INTO `users` (`firstname`, `lastname`,`email`, `password`, `gender`, `country`, `state`) VALUES('firstname','lastname','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email'])."', '".md5(md5($_POST['email']).$_POST['password'])."','gender','country')";
```

well this, considering you just forgot to input the credentials in firstname,lastname,etc.. or you can just replace those with a `NULL` if you prefer not to in your program.

Comment: this does not insert data at all into the database.

Comment: can you add the code of your connection? or check names of your columns. does it match the ones in the code? no one has answered your riddle, maybe the error is in another part of your code.

Comment: <?php
 
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "info");
   
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
 
    die("Could not connect to database");
 
}
   
 
 ?>

Comment: do you initialize which schema to use? add this if not and change yourDatabase in the parameter with the schema your are going to use -->  <?php  mysqli_select_db($link,'yourDatabase') or die(mysqli_connect($link)); ?>